# How to build a 4-bit full adder that shows result on 2 7-segment LEDs, without using Arduino?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm required to create a 4-bit full adder (ALU actually), that displays result on 2 7-segment LEDs with both are common cathode, using only 74HC283, CD4511 and some other logic gates. I'm confused on how to get a result higher than 9, and how to separate the signal to 2 LEDs.

Comment: A typical datasheet for [74283](https://mil.ufl.edu/4712/docs/sn74ls283rev5.pdf) shows carry in and carry out pins. An example circuit for [4511](https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/4000-series-integrated-circuits/ic-4511/) shows the interfacing. I suggest you build these separately and integrate when you understand how the chips work.

Comment: Use a bunch of 74LS-series digital chips.  Like we did in prehistoric times.

Comment: You need to research BCD.